# php returns null while mysql returns value for a user variable

Tags: php, mysql

The following query returns '5' when run using MySql Workbench but returns null using PHP, against the same local apache server:

```
SELECT @distance_in_km from branch where (@distance_in_km := 5) limit 1
```

On the other hand, when the query is

```
SELECT 5 as distance_in_km from branch limit 1
```

both workbench and PHP return 5.

I know I can solve it (get the field distance_in_km to have the value 5 as a result of the query) by modifying the first query as follows:

```
SELECT 5 as distance_in_km, @distance_in_km from branch where (@distance_in_km := 5) limit 1
```

In this case workbench returns '5,5' and PHP returns '5, null' which is fine for me because I get the value using json so I can look for the field 'distance_in_km' instead of '@distance_in_km'.

However, my real query is much more complicated and I want to avoid calculating the field 'distance_in_km' twice.

**EDIT 1**

It looks as if the problem lies in the way PHP evaluates the user variable 'distance_in_km'. On further testing I found out that although PHP returns null values it does know it's true value, because when adding a WHERE test, PHP evaluates correctly:

```
SELECT @distance_in_km from branch where (@distance_in_km := 5) <= 4 limit 1
```

PHP returns 0 records, whereas changing the 4 to 5 in the above test, PHP returns 1 record.

On the other hand, PHP does not sort properly when adding the clause 'ORDER BY @distance_in_km' (it returns the records sorted by the Primary key, which shows PHP is using the null value of '@distance_in_km' instead of it's real value.

**EDIT 2**

PHP version 5.5.12,  Apache version 2.4.9, MYSQL version 5.6.17 (all taken from the wampserver 2.5 menu).

From the same menu I opened MySQL console, and running the queries above and got the result as from PHP. Here is the session

**using the console:**

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 476
Server version: 5.6.17 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use q;
Database changed
mysql> SELECT @distance_in_km from branch where (@distance_in_km := 5) limit 1;
+-----------------+
| @distance_in_km |
+-----------------+
| NULL            |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @distance_in_km from branch where (@distance_in_km := 5) <= 4 limit 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @distance_in_km from branch where (@distance_in_km := 5) <= 5 limit 1;
+-----------------+
| @distance_in_km |
+-----------------+
|               5 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**PHP Code**

```
$query = "SELECT @distance_in_km from branch where (@distance_in_km := 5) <= 5 limit 1";
$result = $db->query($query) or die('Err: Table not found: ' . mysql_error());
echo json_encode($result->fetch_row());
```

**EDIT 3**

According to the modified SELECT statement suggested by @Stan I tried changing my code but was not successful. One can see that distance_in_km does not get the proper values from branch.

```
mysql> SELECT @distance_in_km, latitude from branch, (SELECT @distance_in_km := latitude from branch) as uservar limit 3;
+-----------------+-----------+
| @distance_in_km | latitude  |
+-----------------+-----------+
| 32.0616233      | 32.180644 |
| 32.0616233      | 32.195598 |
| 32.0616233      | 32.197176 |
+-----------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT 4**

```
SELECT @distance_in_km, co.*, c.*
FROM `branch` c
LEFT JOIN open_hours co ON c.open = co.id,
(SELECT @distance_in_km := 111.1111 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * 
    COS(RADIANS('32.177242')) * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS('34.863834')) + SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) * 
    SIN(RADIANS('32.177242')))) from branch) as uservar 
WHERE c.company='1' and @distance_in_km <= 20
ORDER BY @distance_in_km LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

**EDIT 5**

Until a better solution comes up I ended defining the calculation as a UDF (User defined function) and I call it 3 times in the same SELECT!!!. Very inefficient but I see no other way. Thus the SELECT looks now:

```
SELECT distance_in_km(latitude, 32.177242, longitude, 34.863834) as km, c.latitude, c.longitude, c.id FROM `branch` c
            WHERE c.company='1' and distance_in_km(latitude, 32.177242, longitude, 34.863834) <= 20
            ORDER BY distance_in_km(latitude, 32.177242, longitude, 34.863834) LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

On further testing it looks like it works also if I use the variable km in the ORDER BY so that I have the function twice in the SELECT

```
SELECT distance_in_km(latitude, 32.177242, longitude, 34.863834) as km, c.latitude, c.longitude, c.id FROM `branch` c
            WHERE c.company='1' and distance_in_km(latitude, 32.177242, longitude, 34.863834) <= 20
            ORDER BY km LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Please state your PHP version and the using MySQL driver.

Comment: Let's see the PHP code that reproduces the issue, please.

Comment: @Matt Gibson - the PHP code is the same SELECT I posted in EDIT 2. Anyway here is the relevant code:

Comment: Yes, but how values get bound depends on the PHP and the driver. Are you really using the long-deprecated mysql extension?

Comment: _“It looks as if the problem lies in the way PHP evaluates the user variable 'distance_in_km'”_ – it’s an SQL variable, so PHP doesn’t “evaluate” it in any way …

Answer (score 2):

You should probably read this: [MySQL user variables guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html)

Specifically this:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> SET @a = @a + 1; For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get
>   the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following
>   statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then
>   do an assignment second:
>
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...; However, the order of evaluation for
>   expressions involving user variables is undefined.

Short version: variable gets bound after query execution in your case, so it hasn't got any value. Try executing your query twice **in a same session** as a proof of such "undefined" behaviour.

**UPD:**
If you really want to bind variable and use it in the same statement, you might want to try selecting from subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT @distance_in_km from branch, (SELECT @distance_in_km := 5) as uservar limit 1
```

I consider it bad practice, but it works and I understand that sometimes you don't have a choice, so use it wisely, I guess.

Comment: As a general rule, you are right, but I don't think I have an option because in the real query the user variable is using data from a table to calculate distance and based on the distance it decides if to include the row or not. The MySQL guide also states that the WHERE clause is evaluated first, and we see it because when I added <= 4 it correctly did not return any row. So if it has the right value, where did it go?

Comment: @Zvi you actually got an answer in your question about WHERE clause example. It's evaluated first, but it produces 0 rows instead of null for other reasons. Try this query: SELECT @ distance_in_km from branch where null <= 4 limit 1; It is evaluated first and this where condition will never produce any result, thus 0 rows.

Comment: @Zvi it's probably easier to understand if you treat null as "a missing unknown value" (this is a quote from mysql manual), which differs from 0 rows - which is known value of 0 row size

Comment: @Zvi I updated my answer with a workaround that might be useful for you, but still I strongly suggest rethinking your variable usage

Comment: _“but I don't think I have an option because in the real query the user variable is using data from a table to calculate distance and based on the distance it decides if to include the row or not”_ – well maybe someone can suggest an alternative, if you’d describe what you are actually trying to _achieve_ here (instead of just showing an “example” query that doesn’t seem to make much sense.)

Comment: To answer @CBroe: what I am trying to do is select rows based on a distance. In the SELECT I provide source  latitude and longitude, and I calculate distance_in_km based on the latitude and longitude that are in the table. I am sorting the result in the order of the distance from my source and I want to get rows within a certain distance from the source.

Comment: So does that calculation involve values from multiple rows or something, or why do you need to use a user variable in the first place?

Comment: Posted the (almost) actual query in EDIT 3 above

Comment: Sorry @CBroe, but I deleted that code since I was able to duplicate the problem with a simple SELECT. To answer your question, the calculation does not involve multiple tables (just from one) but the query involves multiple tables with 3 LEFT JOIN. I need the user variable because it uses data supplied by me at each SELECT (the source coordinates). and that data changes from SELECT to SELECT (it is not constant)

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t see what you need user variables for. And I don’t see no JOINs either. And not even your data model and a basic explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: OK @CBroe, I added the core part of the query. If you can see how to avoid the user variable than I will be happy to change the query. (I removed from the full query few parts including 2 LEFT JOIN that are not related to the user variable).

Comment: @zvi: My reply was to long for a comment. Please check if my answer reflects what you are actually trying to do, and if I am right in my assumption as to why you felt compelled to use user variables here in the first place.

Comment: See my edit 5 - that exactly what I ended up doing - although to simplify the query I moved the calculation to a UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Now from your Edit #4 it looks to me as if your only reasoning for using user variables here is that you want to not only SELECT the calculated value, but use it in your WHERE clause as well …?

In that case, you should rather try and repeat the calculation in the WHERE clause (as was already pointed out, because of *when* the WHERE clause gets evaluated, you can not use dynamically calculated aliased “column” values in there.)

```
SELECT
  co.*,
  c.*,
  (111.1111 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * …) AS distance_in_km
FROM `branch` c
LEFT JOIN open_hours co ON c.open = co.id
WHERE
  c.company='1'
    AND
  (111.1111 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * …) <= 20
ORDER BY distance_in_km
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

(Using the aliased column `distance_in_km` in the ORDER BY clause again is fine, since that is evaluated at a later time.)

Now this might *sound* terribly inefficient at first, because it looks like the same expensive calculation is done twice – but in reality, the query optimizer should be able to recognize that, so that it is actually calculated only once.

Give that a try, and see if this gives you the desired results – and how it performs.

Comment: Just in case: you can avoid doing calculation twice by moving this condition from WHERE clause to HAVING. It might hurt query perfomance a bit, but still worth a try, considering we don't know dataset size

Comment: @Stan: I am aware of that, but depending on factors like the size of the data set, the performance impact might be quite huge. HAVING is applied “late” (which is why using an aliased column will work there, as opposed to in the WHERE clause) – but it therefor also means that _all_ records will be put into the temporary result set first, and only then filtered out afterwards – which can quite easily lead to it being put onto the hard disk first. And again, I don’t think my suggestion would mean that the calculation is actually performed twice, the query optimizer should be able to handle this.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, it was more like a suggestion for Zvi to try out on an actual database. As far as optimizer goes, it seems to live a very mysterious life sometimes, especially on cheap calculations and small datasets. And still, dataset might be so small, that post-filtering with HAVING clause might give better performance if optimizer won't be able to optimize calculation part. Anyway, just a suggestion, nothing more

Comment: OK, we can certainly agree on “YMMV” :-), and that it is always worth to try out different approaches and see which one gives the best results.